# make read.csv not see single white spaces as a deliminator in R

Tags: r

I have many dataframes that at times looking something like this:

```
EC number   hits    family distribution
3.2.1.x 3   3 CBM32
3.2.1.1 2   2 CBM41
3.2.1.4 2   2 CBM3
2.4.1.18    1   1 CBM48
3.2.1.14    4   1 CBM2  1 CBM5  2 CBM16
3.2.1.39    4   3 CBM13 1 CBM32
3.2.1.50    1   1 CBM32
3.2.1.55    1   1 CBM13
3.2.1.68    2   2 CBM48
```

for the final column there is somtimes multiple entries seperated via a space.

I am using this to read it into R:

```
test=read.csv("path/to/summary.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

But I get the following output:

```
    EC.number  hits family.distribution
1   3.2.1.x 3   3 CBM32
2   3.2.1.1 2   2 CBM41
3   3.2.1.4 2   2 CBM3
4   2.4.1.18    1   1 CBM48
5   3.2.1.14    4   1 CBM2
6   1 CBM5  2 CBM16 
7   3.2.1.39    4   3 CBM13
8   1 CBM32     
9   3.2.1.50    1   1 CBM32
10  3.2.1.55    1   1 CBM13
11  3.2.1.68    2   2 CBM48
```

How can I get around this? I think i have explained my issue but please feel free to ask for more information if I have not :)

Comment: A data frame will not be able to hold more than one entry per row for one column. Perhaps you could read it in line by line and create a list() though. I can't think of an easy one line solution.

Comment: @JAQuent s there a way to make it either smash together the last column, or ignore it. I tried [,1:2] at the end but it still ends up with the same results.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That would only work it I was able to read in the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an read the data as a string, then modify it (for example replacing all tabs by a single space using `gsub`) and **then** read it as a data.frame:

```
# Read the csv as text, so we can run it through gsub
#
file_connection <- file("path_to_csv.csv")
text <- readLines(file_connection)
close(file_connection)
```

After reading the content of the file as a string we can deal with the text "formatting"

Without seeing the actual raw string it's impossible for me to tell what you need to do here, but the idea is to fix the structure using `gsub`:

For Example: Here we replace a space in one of the colnames with underscores:

```
santized_names <- gsub("EC number", "EC_number", text, fixed=TRUE)
```

And then we replace one or more subsequent spaces or tabs with a comma.

```
sanitized <- gsub("[ \t]+", ",", santized_names)
```

After all the fixing is done and the content looks right, we stich the string back together,  adding a newline character after each element

```
sanitized <- paste0(sanitized, collapse="\n")
```

The resulting string can be read as if it was the content of a .csv using the `text` argument

```
df <- read.csv(text=sanitized)
```